# Scrapy: Trying to iterate nested items but not producing desired output

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very much new to Python and Scrapy, but when I tried to iterate nested html elements, it is not producing desired result.

Below is the HTML, i am trying to scrap.

```
<div class="level1" role="main">
<div class="level2">
    <h1 id="fullStoreHeading" class="class_h1">Page Title</h1>
    <div class="fsdColumn_3">
        <div class='fsdDeptBox'>
            <img alt="" src="" aria-hidden="true" height="100%" width="100%">
            <h2 class="fsdDeptTitle">TV</h2>
            <div class='fsdDeptCol'>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1001">Samsung</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1002">Vizio</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1003">Element</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='fsdDeptBox'>
            <img alt="" src="" aria-hidden="true" height="100%" width="100%">
            <h2 class="fsdDeptTitle">Laptop</h2>
            <div class='fsdDeptCol'>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1004">Apple</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1005">Microsoft</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1006">Dell</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="fsdColumn_3">
        <div class='fsdDeptBox'>
            <img alt="" src="" aria-hidden="true" height="100%" width="100%">
            <h2 class="fsdDeptTitle">Video Game Console</h2>
            <div class='fsdDeptCol'>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1007">Xbox One</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1008">Xbox 360</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1009">PS 5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='fsdDeptBox'>
            <img alt="" src="" aria-hidden="true" height="100%" width="100%">
            <h2 class="fsdDeptTitle">SSD</h2>
            <div class='fsdDeptCol'>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1010">Samsung Evo</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1011">Crucial</a>
                <a class="class_a" href="/test?_encoding=UTF8&id=1012">Sandisk</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output I am trying to generate from the above html is a list of:

Product Category -> Brand -> Id

E.g.

TV

```
   Samsung 1001

   Vizio 1002

   Element 1003
```

Laptop

```
  Apple 1004

  Microsoft 1005

  Dell 1006
```

Video Game Console

```
  Xbox Onen 1007

  Xbox 360 1008

  PS4 1009
```

ProductCategories.py

```
def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=ProductSpiderItem(), response=response)

    titles = response.xpath('//*[@class="fsdDeptTitle"]')

    for title in titles:

        Product_Category= title.xpath('text()').extract()

        l.add_value('Product_Category', Product_Category)

        for brnd in 
          title.xpath('//*[@class="fsdDeptCol"]/a[@class="class_a"]'):

                Brand = brnd.xpath('text()').extract()
                l.add_value('Brand', Brand)

    return l.load_item()
```

At this moment it is printing all the product categories from "Outer For Loop" once and the "Inner For Loop" is printing all the brands irrespective of the product categories and the "Inner For Loop" prints all the brands whenever the "Outer For Loop" runs.

I would really appreciate any help to resolve the issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your first 'for' loop sends it to iterate through the `<h2 class="fsdDeptTitle">SSD</h2>` part of the HTML.  Then what you're trying to do is look within that code to find `class=class_a`. It can't do that because the first 'for' loop is too specific to also select the HTML where 'class_a' is.

You can fix this by having your 'for' loops look one level higher in the HTML.

```
titles = response.xpath("//*[@class='fsdDeptBox']")
for title in titles:
    Product_Category=title.xpath('text()').extract()
    l.add_value('Product_Category', Product_Category)

    for brnd in title.xpath('div[@class="fsdDeptCol"]'):
        Brand = brnd.xpath('*/text()').extract()
        l.add_value('Brand', Brand)
    return l.Load_item()
```

I changed the first 'for' loop to select enough of the HTML to include a path to the 'class_a' text

Side note. I don't know much about the correct HTML terms but I hope this still made sense.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put * after // while writing this post. I have edited the post.
Per your suggestion, I tried '*[@class="fsdDeptCol"]/a[@class="class_a"]' ...but it is not returning any records for brands.

Comment: I edited my answer to better answer the question.  I saved the HTML given as a file on my computer and opened it with scrapy shell.  I was able to get the outputs desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check a bit more how [ItemLoader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)s work. They also depend on how your items and item loaders are defined, for example let's assume you've defined like this:

```
class ProductItem(Item):
    category = Field()
    brand = Field()
class ProductItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = ProductItem
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

then you could do something like this:

```
for product in response.css('.fsdDeptCol a'):
    il = ProductItemLoader(selector=product)
    il.add_xpath('category', './ancestor::*/preceding-sibling::h2/text()')
    il.add_xpath('brand', './text()')
    yield il.load_item()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...is there any best way to extract "id" from href value. I could able to extract the entire string from href value.

Comment: sure, assuming you've the `id` field (and the correct imports from w3lib and scrapy's processors) just add something like `il.add_xpath('id', './@href', MapCompose(lambda x: url_query_parameter(x, 'id')))`

Comment: Thanks again. I wish i could give you another vote. Could please refer me to any good article or book where I can learn these advance technique like MapCompose etc.

Comment: Glad it worked! (I think that you can mark this question as answered:) ) I really like the docs https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html you can also check the tests from scrapy's repo